# PHP Regex end operator to be 6th from the start

Tags: php, regex

I want to get value of a data, that has many params within it (the page is actually too big but I'll put the thing I need and what I'm using)

```
&data=a=3&b=token&c=1424551692&d=1&e=kingkongtitle&zxc=7ee&f33=a22asf8asfl2sdiog383g&hh=a22asf8asfl2sdiog383g-dwToc&
```

I use the following regex but it makes sense that it gets the value between the start and stop:

```
preg_match("/data\=(.+?)\&/",$output, $newvar);
```

The above is getting only "a=3" it should get all the complete. I could assign a param that comes after the last & but actually it changes all the time so its not possible for me to do that.

I was thinking of a solution where I could say that the start value is the one assigned above and the end is the 5th or 6th "&" and it ignores the other & that comes before 5th or 6th.

Comment: If you want to match to the end of the line then use a $: `preg_match("/data\=(.+?)\&$/",$output, $newvar);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the {6} to repeat the same string again up to 6 times

```
 preg_match_all("/data=((?:[^&]*&){6})/", $in, $out);
```

or even

```
 preg_match_all("/data=((?:.*&){6})/", $in, $out);
```